# Logback - Where do XML documents get their variables injected

Tags: java, xml, spring, logback, slf4j

I'm working on a `Spring Boot` project and I've seen logging done with `slf4j` and `logback`. The following is a `logback-spring.xml` I've seen that logs errors to the console in addition to a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyyMMddd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

My question is, where do things like `${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}` and `${LOG_FILE}` get their actual data from at compile/run time or whenever this is used? I'm curious because `${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyyMMddd}.%i` usually leaves me with logs named like `LOG_FILE_IS_UNDEFINED-201707012.0` which leads me to the obvious conclusion that `LOG_FILE` isn't defined anywhere, and I would like to remedy this.

I've seen resources like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html), but they don't seem to provide enough details on the inner-workings of how the values are injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot comes with a default configuration for logback. The jar has embedded the xml configuration files for the different appenders. You can have a look to them at GitHub project: [Default spring-boot logback configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback)

You can override that configuration including your own xml configuration files.
[Configure Logback for logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging)

You are getting undefined file because you have probably not defined the property `logging.file`

Comment: Thanks, in addition to your information I have learned that in my Spring Boot project we have a few specifications that may help others that find this. There is an `application-<env>.properties` files for each environment as well as `application-<username>.properties` for each developer and to use one specifically we add `-Dspring.profiles.active=<username OR env>` to the VM options in the run/debug configuration. Inside the specific user or environment profile is where we define things like the `logging.file` and `logging.level.<package>` to specify the granularity of the logging.

Comment: so if i just want to add log numbers, what do i do, I keep getting parsing errors

Comment: @KalpeshSoni the default configuration for the file appender adds numbers to the log. `<fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>` (the %i) and it uses `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy`

Comment: that is for name of the log file, i was talking about java statement line number

Comment: @KalpeshSoni `%line` allows you to print the line number from where the logging request was called. https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

you can refer my logback.xml file for as a reference...
and for a sample basic spring-boot, maven and theme based application also check  :[project on GitHub](https://github.com/satyaprakashmehta/spring-boot-2.0.0)

```
<!-- <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" /> -->
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="../logs" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <!-- roll over POLICY FOR daily -->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>25MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="logging.level.com.sp.mehta" level="INFO"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<logger name="logging.level.org.hibernate" level="ERROR"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```